# Meaning of the Slope/Gradient of an Exponential Function Displayed on a Logarithmic Scale

Tags: exponential-function, slope

I am currently dealing with data that is almost exponential. An exponential function shows as a line if plotted on a single logarithmic ordinate. To proof that it is of almost exponential behaviour I plotted the data set in a diagram with a single logarithmic ordinate. This line displayed has a gradient or - for it's a line - a slope. I am comparing two different data sets. The slope of the two data sets differ from one another.

Does anybody know what kind of information I can take out the gradient / slope of the line of an exponential function displayed in a single logarithmic ordinate?

The picture below clarifies the issue:

[Showing the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c32Tl.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: What's the context for this data? What are you measuring in this case? What are MS1 ... MS6 ? PS: The last graph is very difficult to read. Rewrite the $x$-coordinates ...

Comment: For right now I am rather interested in the math behind it, which is why I left out further details. The x-axis in (d) is of the same scale as the one in (b), so one can see the two different slopes immediately.

So coming from a standard form of an exponential function $y = a \cdot b^{x+c} + q$, which variables would influence the slope of the line in the logarithmic graph?

Comment: Also: Do you happen to know if the slope will tell me anything else rather than that one curve decreases faster than the other?

Comment: When thinking about these, it's always useful to write down some equations. Without any logarithms, we assume that the graph has the form
$$
y=f(x)
$$
Now, we know that we are plotting the logarithmic $y$-axis. Therefore, we take the logarithm on both sides:
$$
\ln y = \ln(f(x))
$$
From the graph, we see that when plotted logarithmically, the graph is approximately a line. Therefore
$$
\ln = \ln f(x) \approx ax +b
$$
Now we know that the function is approximately of the form
$$
f(x) \approx e^{ax+b} = C_1 e^{ax}
$$
So that's at least the math behind these things ...

Comment: So it should be clear that the slope of the line on the logarithmic scale is the factor $a$.

Comment: Thank you. This already helps a great deal!
One more question: how do you get from $e^{ax+b}$ to $C_1e^{ax}$?

Comment: $$
e^{ax+b} = e^{ax} \cdot e^b = e^b \cdot e^{ax}= C_1 e^{ax}
$$
So I renamed the constant $e^b$ as $C_1$.

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote all your comments if I'd already be allowed to. For now a "thank you" has to do.